# In Microsoft Graph Api message Id has changed without any reason

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Time to time we get error response for following request to Microsoft Graph Api:

`GET /users/{userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}`

```
"Code: ErrorItemNotFound
Message: The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.
..."
```

After investigation we found that Ids of messages were changed.
My question is, why and when Id of message could be changed? Is it bug or normal behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Immutable Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) might help you. They also explain the reason of changing Item ID in that article.